# Save current User into field within array in Mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

Here is a relevant part of my Schema, where I'll make reservations to a "space":

```
var spaceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
spaceName: String,
scheduledDates: [{
    scheduledDates: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        username: String
    }
}]
});
```

Author should be the current user that's logged in. Here is my route to update those fields:

```
router.put('/:space_id/schedule', function(req, res) {
Space.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.space_id, {
    '$push': { 'scheduledDates': req.body.space, 'author': req.user._id }
}, { "new": true, "upsert": true }, function(err, space) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(req.body.space);
    }
});
});
```

I can't access "author" correctly, because it's inside the array. What can I do to update this array, adding a new date and user to make the reservation?

Thank you

---

*UPDATE*

I tried to use "_id" instead of "id" in my property but got the same result. It seems like it's ignoring the "author" field, and only saving "scheduledDates"

So the schema was like this:

```
    scheduledDates: [{
    scheduledDates: String,
    author: {
        _id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        username: String
    }
}]
```

And then in my route, I changed what I was 'pushing':

```
'$push': { 'scheduledDates': req.body.space, 'author._id': req.user._id }
```

---

*UPDATED 2*

Changed the way I was getting the object to push:

```
    '$push': {
        'scheduledDates': {
            'scheduledDates': req.body.space,
            'author': { _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username }
        }
    }
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
message: 'Cast to string failed for value "{ scheduledDates: \'04/11/2017\' }" at path "scheduledDates"',
    name: 'CastError',
    stringValue: '"{ scheduledDates: \'04/11/2017\' }"',
    kind: 'string',
    value: [Object],
    path: 'scheduledDates',
    reason: undefined } } }
```

Comment: You really should not use `id` as a property name in your schema. This is actually a reserved alias in mongoose for `_id`, so you should have `'author': { _id: { type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }, ... }` instead. Then you simply change to `'author._id': req.user._id` in the `$push`. Not sure about the additional `username` property in the array entry. If that is also a property of `req.user` then you can similarly address that one as well.

Comment: Or even `'$push': { 'scheduledDates': req.body.space, 'author': { _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username }  }`, since it is a `$push` afterall and not as if you are updating specific properties within an existing array member.

Comment: @NeilLunn I just tried that, but got the same result. It doesn't give me an error or anything, but it's saving only the "scheduledDate" to my database, and ignoring the "author"... Any other thoughts on how to access the author?

Comment: Please amend you question to show what you "actually tried". Remember that the only thing people can see that you are doing is what you actually include in the content. Saying you "did something" does not mean you did the "correct thing".

Comment: @NeilLunn Update with your suggestion

Comment: What does `mongoose.set('debug', true)` show you? Adding that to your program causes all statements to log to the terminal. If `req.user._id` is `undefined` then mongoose will strip it from the statement.

Comment: @NeilLunn `req.user._id` is actually not `undefined`, I can console.log it. Do you know if by passing `'author': req.user._id`, I can actually get to the 'author' field inside of the scheduledDates array?

Comment: Missed your typo. `scheduledDates` is both the name of the array as well as the property so: `'$push': { 'scheduledDates': { 'scheduledDates': req.body.space, 'author': { _id: req.user._id } } }`

Comment: @NeilLunn Tried that and updated again with your suggestions

Comment: That's actually a completely different issue since `req.body.space` contains an object. You could therefore either use `req.body.space.scheduledDates` to specify the property, or you could instead "merge" the new property as in `$push': { 'scheduledDates': Object.assign(req.body.space,{  'author': { _id: req.user._id } }) }`

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you so much!!! It works perfectly now :)